# Does the different partitions occupy the space of the hard disk with a order?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, sd-card, dd

Let's say the disk has the position from 0 to 4049 MB.
if the size of partition 1 is 50 MB, so it took the position from 0 to 49?

My assumption comes from the following story:

I am trying to back up my Linux System(a Raspberry PI). Then I googled how should I do it and shrink it to the size of it rather than back up the whole sd-card.

Then I found an answer says that I should at first check how big the boot partition and the main partition are (with gparted). Then run dd, e.g.

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=sysbackup.img bs=1M count=1024
```

So this count is the same as the size of the two partitions.

But I thought dd just scan the whole disk in order. That means the partitions are also located actually in order?

Comment: Tools like Superduper (for Mac) copy content. You can copy a 500GB partition to 300GB if the source disk uses less than 300GB. AFAIK dd copies bytes, doesn't analyse the content. So it will copy that entire 500GB. And if that's two partitions, yes, it will copy them in the order they are on the disk. I'm not 100% sure on this though.

Comment: Instead of wondering, you can use GParted to obtain the actual (first & last) sector addresses of each partition using the `Information` pull-down menu item.

Comment: @sawdust that's a nice trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition locations are described by partition tables. The two most common types of partition tables today are the [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) and the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table). Details differ, but in both cases, a few sectors of the disk are set aside to describe where each individual partition begins and ends, as well as to hold additional metadata, such as a type code, a name (GPT only), and so on. An OS knows enough to look for a partition table on a disk, to figure out what type it uses (MBR, GPT, or something more exotic), and then to interpret a range of sectors as being a partition that's distinct from another range of sectors.

In the case of both MBR and GPT, the order of partitions in the partition table, and therefore the partition numbers assigned to them (`/dev/sda1` vs. `/dev/sda2`, for instance) does not necessarily match the order in which partitions appear on the disk. That is, `/dev/sda2` might occupy sectors 40 to 1,126,439, and `/dev/sda1` could occupy sectors 1,126,440 to 15,628,053,134. There can also be unpartitioned space (analogous to parts of a bookshelf that hold no books), areas used by the partitioning system, etc. The start point of the first partition is not entirely standardized, although some values are more common than others. Thus, if your goal is to back up an entire disk, you have three choices:

- **Whole-disk backup** -- You can do a low-level backup (using `dd` or some other tool) of the *entire* disk, from sector 0 to the end of the disk. This will have the effect of backing up the partition table, the contents of all partitions, and everything in unpartitioned sections of the disk. When you restore such a backup, it will look just like the original to an OS (give or take questions of the disk model and exact disk size). This is a pretty "dumb" approach, in that it requires no knowledge of the partitions on the disk, what partition table is in use, etc. In part for this reason, it's also relatively inefficient -- you'll likely be backing up areas of the disk that aren't actually in use, which can increase the size of the backup beyond what you probably need. This very inefficiency, although often a drawback, can actually be an advantage in some cases, such as if the disk's data structures are badly damaged -- you can work on the backup to attempt to recover data without worrying about damaging the original. Likewise, you can back up an encrypted disk even if you don't have the decryption key.
- **Whole-partition backup** -- You can use `dd` or a similar tool to perform a "dumb" backup of each partition. When you restore the backup, you'll need to create a fresh partition table, which should probably match the original. Thus, you may need to back up the partition table itself, or at least record the sizes of each partition. (The `dd` backup file sizes may provide this information.) Like a whole-disk backup, such a backup is likely to be space-inefficient, unless most of the disk was unpartitioned and/or the partitions themselves were mostly full. It requires more "smarts" to restore, and as the restored disk might not exactly match the original, some OSes and tools might stop working. The disk might not be bootable, for instance. This approach is basically a compromise between the other two methods.
- **Filesystem-aware backup** -- In this approach, you use a tool that understands the filesystems in use on each partition -- that is, the tool reads NTFS, FAT, ext4fs, HFS+, or whatever filesystem each partition uses. This could be using something like `cp`, `tar`, or `zip` to back up files, using the OS itself to handle the filesystem; or it could be a filesystem-specific tool that can back up at a lower level, while omitting unused parts of the filesystem. Either way, this approach requires much more "smarts" than any other approach, but the advantage is that the backup is likely to be faster and consume less disk space. The drawback is that you'll need more "smarts" in the tool to restore the backup. You may need to take extra steps to make the restored disk bootable again, and you'll certainly need to either back up the partition table itself or know enough to re-create something compatible. This type of backup is a poor choice if the original filesystem has been damaged, since the tool that reads the filesystem might become confused, omit critical data, or even crash.

Which type of tool you'd want to use depends on your needs. If you want a fast backup or one that uses a minimal amount of space *and* if the original is intact, you'd want to use a filesystem-aware backup tool. If the disk is small or damaged, a whole-disk (or at least whole-partition) backup is likely to be better.

In the case of a whole-partition or filesystem-aware backup, you should back up the partition table. How to do this depends on the partition table type. In some cases, recording the output of a partitioning tool should be adequate. For instance, you could type `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and cut-and-paste the output into a text file to record the partitioning data on `/dev/sda`. Some tools offer ways to record the data in more detail. For instance, my own GPT fdisk (`gdisk`, `cgdisk`, and `sgdisk`) enables backing up GPT data to a binary file. This is done with the `b` option on `gdisk`'s main menu, with the "Backup" item in `cgdisk`, or with the `-b`/`--backup` command-line option to `sgdisk`. Whether a simple recording of a partitioning tool's display or a detailed binary backup file like what GPT fdisk produces is necessary depends on your needs, which you haven't specified in enough detail for me to provide advice.

For more on disk partitioning, see:

- [The Wikipedia article on disk partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning)
- [This Howto Geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/184659/beginner-geek-hard-disk-partitions-explained/)
- [This LinuxBSDOS article](http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/11/08/a-beginners-guide-to-disks-and-disk-partitions-in-linux/)

Comment: Thnx! that's very informative!